# Создание голосового синтезатора с нуля

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем здравствуйте! Я сейчас разрабатываю голосового ассистента и хотел бы у вас узнать как разработать свой синтезатор голоса. Хотелось бы узнать как формируется синтез голос, и как нужно озвучивать кусочки звуковых файлов. Был бы рад, если бы вы скинули какие-нибудь сайты где это может быть расписано, а то не могу найти, даже на зарубежных ресурсах

Comment: За основу можно взять [eSpeak](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESpeak). Небольшой. сносно говорит по-русски. Куча wrapper-ов, в том числе и для [python](https://geekbrains.ru/posts/tts_python).

Answer (score 1):

И так. Я нашёл 7 голосов на русском [скачать можно тут](https://github.com/RHVoice/RHVoice/blob/master/doc/en/Binaries.md)

Во! Отыскал тестовый файл с настройкой голоса, его скорости и тд:

```
import pyttsx3

tts = pyttsx3.init()
voices = tts.getProperty('voices')
tts.setProperty('voice', 'ru') 
rate = tts.getProperty('rate')   # получение подробной информации о текущей скорости разговора
tts.setProperty('rate', 150)
# Попробовать установить предпочтительный голос
for voice in voices:
    if voice.name == 'Irina':
        tts.setProperty('voice', voice.id)

tts.say('Добрый вечер всем ! Вы изучаете питон!')

tts.runAndWait()
```

Если не ошибаюсь, то `voices` и `rate` можно вывести через `print`. Первое должно выдать список голосов, а второе - скорость разговора

Comment: Вы не правильно меня поняли. Мне нужно разработать голосовой синтезатор с нуля без использования сторонних программ или компонентов для работы с tts

Comment: @JonnyNamreh, ааааааа. Я думал вам нужен пример с использованием голосов)

Comment: @DGDays А мне как раз надо было голосов ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, хех) Пользуйся на здоровье ;)